# How to convert a bunch of arrays into a single object?

Tags: javascript

Here is what im doing:

onClick, grab details immediate subnodes and publish it on html. Status = DONE // This works well

NOW, I am using a bunch of arrays to get this done.

```
node.eachSubnode(function(node) {
                   title[title.length] = node.name; // This is what i want to modify
                   data[data.length] = node.data; // This is what i want to modify
                });
```

Here is how they look currently:

```
title = ['Coffee', 'Tea'];
data = ["Americans", "Britishers"]; // i use a loop to iterate through these arrays and append to html.
```

Here is what  i want it to be:

```
var preference = {
title: 'Coffee',
data: 'Americans'
},
{
title: 'Tea',
data: 'Americans
}
```

I want to create this using the node.eachSubnode loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but I think this is what you want:

```
var preferences = [];

node.eachSubnode(function(node) {
    preferences.push({
        title: node.name,
        data: node.data.germ
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, this is perfect. I used preferences[i++] suggested by djdavid98 instead of push. Isn't that faster?

Comment: @sidegeeks It's faster only if you initialize the array with a specific length and the array doesn't require to grow dynamically for added items. However, premature optimizations are very bad because it adds complexity to your code without observable benefits. If you were concerned about performance, then even using the `eachSubnode` iterator is quite slower than iterate an array using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an object that looks exactly like that, I think you need an array with objects. Assuming your node is an array with the `length` property, [this method is the fastest](http://jsperf.com/array-push-vs-array-length23333/9).

```
var preference = new Array(node.length||0), i = 0;
node.eachSubnode(function(node) {
    preference[i++] = {
        title: node.name,
        data: node.data.germ
    };
});
```